# Challenging recurrence relation that depends on composition of integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am overall looking to find an explicit expression for $Z(\pi_a,j,0)$ in terms of the $\lambda$ terms in  $\pi_a$ (a composition of non-negative integers) and $j$.

$\textbf{These are the conditions for the variables that are known}$
$$
(\lambda_v \ge 0) \text{ and } (a > 2)
\\
\pi_a = (\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_a) 
\\
k = \sum_{m=1}^a \lambda_m
\\
0 \le j \le k- \max\{\pi_a\}
\\
\phi(a,j) = \sum_{m=1}^a \lambda_m -j
$$
$\textbf{The recurrence relation & other important info}$

Let $Z(\pi_a,j,m) = Z((\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_{a-1},\lambda_a-m),j)$ the recurrence relation is defined as
$$
Z((\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_{a-1},\lambda_a) = ((k-1)-(j-1)-(\lambda_a-1))Z((\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_{a-1},\lambda_a),j-1) + Z((\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_{a-1},\lambda_a-1),j)
$$
Also known as
$$
Z(\pi_a,j,0) = \phi(a-1,j-1)Z(\pi_a,j-1,1) + Z(\pi_a,j,1)
$$
These are values of functions at specific points
$$
Z(\pi_a,0,m) = 1
\\
Z(\pi_2,j-m,0) = \frac{\lambda_1! \lambda_2!}{(j-m)!(\lambda_1+m-j)!(\lambda_2+m-j)!}
$$
when the 3rd dependent variable in the recurrence relation is equal to the $a^{th}$ $\pi_a$ term (or we have $\lambda_a=0$), we evaluate the composition of integers as if it has $a-1$ terms as $\pi_{a-1}$
$$
Z(\pi_a,j,\lambda_a) = Z(\pi_{a-1},j,0) \tag{A}
$$
Since the variable depends on a composition of non-negative integers.

$\textbf{What I have done}$

I have begun by expanding out the recurrence relation in two different ways

First way:
$$
Z(\pi_a,j,0) = \phi(a-1,j-1) \sum_{w=1}^{\lambda_a} Z(\pi_a,j-1,w) + Z(\pi_{a-1},j,0)
\\
= \sum_{s=1}^{a-2} \phi(a-s,j-1) \sum_{w=1}^{\lambda_{a-s}} Z(\pi_{a-s},j-1,w) + Z(\pi_2,j,0)
$$
Second way
$$
Z(\pi_a,j,0) = \phi(a-1,j-1) Z(\pi_a,j-1,1) + Z(\pi_a,j,1)
\\
= \phi(a-1,j-2)\phi(a-1,j-1) Z(\pi_a,j-2,2)+\phi(a-1,j-1) Z(\pi_a,j-1,2) + Z(\pi_a,j,1)
\\
= \sum_{q=0}^{\lambda_a} \frac{Z(\pi_a,j-q,1+q)}{\phi(a-1,j)} \prod_{v=0}^q \left[\phi(a-1,j-v)\right] 
$$
I have tried to manipulate these two expanded versions many times, but it just seems too rigorous.

$\textbf{EDIT}$

I expanded in a third way which may help
\begin{align*}
z(\pi_a,j,0) = \sum_{m=0}^{\lambda_a} {\lambda_a \choose m} \frac{\phi(a-1,j-m)!}{\phi(a-1,j)!} Z(\pi_{a-1},j-m,0) \tag{3}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
Z(\pi_a,j,r) = \phi(a-1,j-1)\sum_{w=1}^{\lambda_3-r}Z(\pi_a,j-1,r+w) + Z(\pi_{a-1},j,0) \therefore
\\
Z(\pi_a,j,0) = \phi(a-1,j-1)\sum_{w=1}^{\lambda_3}Z(\pi_a,j-1,w) + Z(\pi_{a-1},j,0)
\\
= \phi(a-1,j-1)\phi(a-1,j-2)\sum_{w=1}^{\lambda_3}\sum_{w_1=1}^{\lambda_3-w}Z(\pi_a,j-1,w+w_1)+Z(\pi_{a-1},j-1,0)\phi(a-1,j-1)\sum_{w=1}^{\lambda_3}(1) + Z(\pi_{a-1},j,0)
\\
= \sum_{m=0}^{\lambda_a} {\lambda_a \choose m} \frac{\left(\phi(a-1,j)+m\right)!}{\left(\phi(a-1,j)\right)!} Z(\pi_{a-1},j-m,0)\qquad \qquad 
\end{align*}
Since:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{v=m}^{n} \sum_{\pi_m \in C_v} (1) = {\lambda_v \choose m} \text{ Due to definition of binomial coefficient}
\\
\prod_{v=1}^m \phi(a-1,j-v) = \prod_{v=1}^m (\phi(a-1,j)-v) = \frac{\phi(a-1,j)+v)!}{\phi(a-1,j)!}
\end{align*}
$\textbf{EDIT #2}$

By expanding (3) $a-2$ times, I found that
\begin{align*}
Z(\pi_a,j,0) = \sum_{m_1=0}^{\lambda_a} \sum_{m_2=0}^{\lambda_{a-1}} \cdots \sum_{m_{a-2}=0}^{\lambda_3} \left(\prod_{v=1}^{a-2} {\lambda_{a-v+1} \choose m_v} \frac{\phi(a-v,j-m_v)!}{\phi(a-v,j)!}\right) Z(\pi_2,j-\sum_{q=1}^{a-2} m_q,0) 
\\
= \sum_{m=0}^{k-\lambda_1-\lambda_2} \sum_{\gamma_{a-2} \in C_m} \left(\prod_{v=1}^{a-2} {\lambda_{a-v+1} \choose u_v} \frac{\phi(a-v,j-u_v)!}{\phi(a-v,j)!}\right) Z(\pi_2,j-m,0)
\\
= \sum_{m=0}^{k-\lambda_1-\lambda_2} Z(\pi_2,j-m,0)\sum_{\gamma_{a-2} \in C_m} \left(\prod_{v=1}^{a-2} {\lambda_{a-v+1} \choose u_v} \frac{\phi(a-v,j-u_v)!}{\phi(a-v,j)!}\right)
\end{align*}
Where a new composition of integers $\gamma$ with non-negative integer terms is defined:
\begin{align*}
\gamma_{a-2} = (u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_{a-2})
\\
\sum_{q=1}^{a-2} u_q = m
\end{align*}
$\textbf{Possible way to derive solution}$
\begin{align*}
Z(\pi_a,j,0) = \sum_{m=0}^{k-\lambda_1-\lambda_2} Z(\pi_2,j-m,0)\sum_{\gamma_{a-2} \in C_m} \left(\prod_{v=1}^{a-2} {\lambda_{a-v+_1} \choose u_v} \frac{\phi(a-v,j-u_v)!}{\phi(a-v,j)!}\right)
\end{align*}
But I am looking for a better looking formula,I also have questions about if the expression converges to a value that enables me to calculate values for $(j < k-\lambda_1-\lambda_2)$. I also want to have this summation simplified if possible
$$
\sum_{\gamma_{a-2} \in C_m} \left(\prod_{v=1}^{a-2} {\lambda_{a-v+1} \choose u_v} \frac{\phi(a-v,j-u_v)!}{\phi(a-v,j)!}\right)
\\
= \sum_{\gamma_{a-2} \in C_m} \left(\prod_{v=1}^{a-2} {\phi(a-v,j-u_v) \choose u_v} \frac{\lambda_{a-v+1}!}{(\lambda_{a-v+1}-u_v)!}\right)
$$
$\textbf{Generating functions Attempt}$

Letting 
$$
\sigma(j,m)= \sum_{\gamma_{a-2} \in C_m} \left(\prod_{v=1}^{a-2} {\phi(a-v,j-u_v) \choose u_v} \frac{\lambda_{a-v+1}!}{(\lambda_{a-v+1}-u_v)!}\right)
$$
\begin{align*}
\sigma(j,m)x^{k-\lambda_1-\lambda_2-m} = x^{k-\lambda_1-\lambda_2-m}\sum_{\gamma_{a-2} \in C_m}\prod_{v=1}^{a-2} \left( {\phi(a-v,j-u_v) \choose u_v} \frac{\lambda_{a-v+1}!}{(\lambda_{a-v+1}-u_v)!}\right)
\\
\sum_{\gamma_{a-2} \in C_m}\prod_{v=1}^{a-2} \left( {\phi(a-v,j-u_v) \choose u_v} \frac{d^{u_v}}{dx^{u_v}}\left[x^{\lambda_{a-v+1}}\right]\right)
\\
=
\sum_{\gamma_{a-2} \in C_m}\prod_{v=1}^{a-2} \left( \frac{\phi(a-v,j-u_v)!}{\phi(a-v,j)!} \frac{1}{u_v!}\frac{d^{u_v}}{dx^{u_v}}\left[x^{\lambda_{a-v+1}}\right]\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: The recurrence relations you provide seem insufficient to determine the function: your results indicate you have other relations not stated. Also, you should provide info on where this comes from: eg when you say "We find..." it sounds like a result not an assumption, but it does not follow from any of the previous assumptions.

Comment: @EinarRødland I fixed up the wording a bit. The results that I have obtained were from information provided in the question, i simply expanded out the recurrence relation arbitrarily. I do not understand what you mean by my recurrence relations are insufficient to determine the function, could you be more specific? When $j=0$, the variable is defined, when $a=2$ the variable is defined. Those are the only two variables being manipulated, so it must be enough to determine the value, unless you see something i don't.

Comment: For $Z(\pi_a,j,m)$ you have a relation between the $m=0$ expressions and $m=1$ expressions, but none for higher $m$. Eg I see no relation involving $Z((1,2,3,4),2,5)$. Is $\pi_a$ a set or a list: ie are the $\lambda_i$ distinct? Where does the "We find..." clause come from? And, again, where does this problem come from or what has motivated it?

Comment: @EinarRødland $\pi_a$ is a set of integers $\lambda$ such that $k = \sum_{m=1}^a \lambda_m$ (non-negative integer values determined beforehand, so distinct i suppose), this problem comes from a bump in the road for defining a conjecture of mine. The 'we find' clause comes from expanding the recurrence relation until $m=\lambda_a$, making $\lambda_a-m=0$ in the set. That is what the operation defines, hence the "essentially, eliminating the a-th element of the set πa". If there is a better way to express this i am open to that. I realize it may be informally expressed in my question.

Comment: @EinarRødland Add-on to other comment (too many char.) 
$$
Z(\pi_a,j,\lambda_a) = Z(\pi_{a-1},j,0)
$$
To answer your question about $m>\lambda_a$, that is not possible as it shifts to next term in the set $\pi_a$, i added more information in the question that may help verify.

Comment: It seems to me you're applying assumptions or relations that are not stated in the problem. Eg why can't $m>\lambda_a$? What relations do you apply when $m$ is not in $\pi_a$?

Comment: Same problem applies to eg $Z((1,3,4),2,2)$. Or how would you compute $Z((2,3,4),1,0)$ or $Z((2,3,4),2,0)$ using only the stated relations? They don't seem to be determined by the relations.

Comment: @EinarRødland Lets take for example $Z((1,3,4),2,0)$, $k=1+3+4=8$, $j=2$, $a=3$ we have:
\begin{align*}
Z((1,3,4),2,0) = (k-j-\lambda_3+1)Z((1,3,3),1,1) + Z((1,3,3),2,1)
\\
= 3(k-(j-1)-\lambda_3+1)Z((1,3,2),0,2)+(k-j-\lambda_3+1)Z(1,3,2),1,2)+Z((1,3,2),2,2)
\end{align*}
Note when $j=0$ the $Z$ term is equal to 1. You would continue this pattern, until $m=4$ then this would occur:
$$
Z((1,3,0),2,4) = Z((1,3),2,0) = \frac{1!3!}{2!(3-2)!(1-2)!}=0
$$
The other terms when completely expanded will sum together to create the sum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43712/discussion-between-eric-lawson-and-einar-rodland).